# How to make ListView item change Layout1 to Layout2 on click and back to Layout1 on click again

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my app I add item to ListView after pressing button. Default List item has RelativeLayout1 with 3 TextViews, selected item has RelativeLayout2 with 5 TextViews. XML code of RelativeLayout2 is inside RelativeLayout1 with  visibility GONE sttement.

It should work like this: 
when pressing an item, it should swap layouts - I made it by making 2nd layout visible and text from layout1 transparent (yay or nay?), it should work on any number of list items, while now I can press only the first one and the layouts spaw. Then, after scrolling the ListView, the same and only this item should remain on its 'selected' state, and after pressing this item again it should go back to the former 1st layout (now it completly does not work).

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Holder holder1;
    holder1 = (Holder) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_1);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutVisible = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutOfSelectedListItem);

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.layoutOfListItem)) {

            relativeLayoutVisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder1.kwota.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder1.opis.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
    else if (view == relativeLayoutVisible){
        relativeLayoutVisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder1.kwota.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder1.opis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        NowaWplata newPayment = (NowaWplata) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        if (newPayment.getFlag() == 1) {
            holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 2) {
            holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 3) {
            holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    }
```

and in custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    NowaWplata newPayment = getItem(position);
    Holder holder1;
    Holder holder2;


    //if there are no items in list - add 1st item
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_item_layout, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.osobaWplata);
        TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kwotaWplata);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opisWplata);

        TextView hourDateSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView dayDateSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView nameSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView valueSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valueFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView descriptionSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem);

        if (newPayment.getFlag() == 1) {
            nameSelected.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 2) {
            nameSelected.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 3) {
            nameSelected.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        holder1 = new Holder(name, value, description);
        holder2 = new Holder(nameSelected, valueSelected, descriptionSelected, hourDateSelected, dayDateSelected);
        view.setTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_1, holder1);
        view.setTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_2, holder2);
    }
    // if there are items in list get holder tag
    else {
        holder1 = (Holder) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_1);
        holder2 = (Holder) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_2);
    }

    //setting text to a new list items
    holder1.osoba.setText("[" + newPayment.getDate() + "]  " + newPayment.getOsoba());
    holder1.kwota.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
    holder1.opis.setText(newPayment.getOpis());
    holder2.hourDate.setText("[" + newPayment.getHourDate() + "]");
    holder2.dayDate.setText(newPayment.getDayDate());
    holder2.osobaSelected.setText(newPayment.getOsoba());
    holder2.kwotaSelected.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
    holder2.opisSelected.setText(newPayment.getOpis());

    //setting different color to Lukasz/Marcelina/Karolina text
    if (newPayment.getFlag() == 1) {
        holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder2.osobaSelected.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 2) {
        holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder2.osobaSelected.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 3) {
        holder1.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        holder2.osobaSelected.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this question still active?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your second RelativeLayout in your first, you probably should create a parent layout and have both your relative layouts inside it. someting like this in your xml.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout ...
        android:id="@+id/layout_one"
        android:visibility="visible"
        .../>
    <RelativeLayout ...
        android:id="@+id/layout_one"
        android:visibility="gone"
        .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a boolean in your item class ,called selected with its getter isSelected() and a setter setSelected(boolean). Lets say listView is a reference to your ListView. And in OnItemClick add(if your item class is called Item:

```
Item item = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
if(item.isSelected()){
    item.setSelected(false);
}
else{
    item.setSelected(true);
}
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() // To redraw your views.
```

At last in your getView method you should have something like that:

```
if(item.isSelected()){
    holder.relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else{
    holder.relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

There your go, you shoudl probably change some variable names to be sure that it is compatible with your project and add the relativeLayout references in your holder but I think this is the best way to go and it is way more clear. And if you want only one item to be selected just ensure to call the setSelected(false); for the item previously selected.